# Perform click to tabtext under TabLayout always gives NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, android-espresso

I would like to perform click on one of my tabs using espresso,

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        ...>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:text="Tab1" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:text="Tab2" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

I tried asserting if it isDisplayed(), and it is

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.tabs), withText("Tab2"), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.container)), isDisplayed()));
```

But when I try to perform click on the text, it results to NoMatchingViewException

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.tabs), withText("Tab2"), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.container)), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

I tried putting it in different lines,

```
1. check if displayed
2. perform click
```

How can we successfully click tabtext under viewPager using espresso?

Tried using the tab IDs, but still same result.
Suggestions to use viewTags does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onView(allOf(withText("Tab2"), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.tabs)))).perform(click());
```

As the view with the text `withText("Tab2")` doesn't have the id `withId(R.id.tabs)` (because its parent is the one with that id) so that's why  you get the `NoMatchingViewException`